# Is there a way to mark an InputStream twice?

Tags: java

I want to make it so I can call `in.mark(512)` to limit my stream to 512 bytes. Then, later I want to limit my stream to 64 bytes. Can I later call `in.mark(64)` and then `in.reset()` but still have the mark of 512 be active? What I'm trying to say is "Can you have a `mark()` and `reset()` stack?"

Comment: By the way, you should go back and mark some answers as 'accepted'.

Comment: Incidentally, in your favourite stream, you may find that mark()/reset() is implemented by reading the data into an array. As an alternative implementation, you could always read the data into an array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least for BufferedInputStream, the answer is definitely no.  It stores `marklimit` and `markpos` fields, which are just simple ints.

You could probably write one, but the functionality is not in the base Java streams.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, that is what inheritance is for.  Extend whatever stream class you are working with and overload the mark and reset methods.

Comment: You have to be careful with doing something like this - you're introducing new functionality to a method which already has a defined contract, therefore changing that contract.  Any code that uses this implicit functionality will later break subtly if you substitute a different subclass that you haven't "tweaked" in this way...

Comment: Depending on how he needs to use the stream he could either inherit and finalize the class where you still have the issue you talked about, or he could wrap the class and add his own functionality.  This would be the preferred way but it won't allow for polymorphism.